# Configuring Automapper in a .NET Core Console App with a data library?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, console-application, automapper

I'm very new to AutoMapper, .NET Core and DI - although I am familiar with .NET Framework. I'm struggling to get AutoMapper to work in an app I've built. The app is a console app, which has a data library attached to it.

I've tried to configure AutoMapper in the `Main()` method of the console app - because as I understand it you need to configure it at the startup point of the app? I'm then creating an instance of a class in the data library which then in turn creates an instance of the `Mappers` class where I do all my mappings. I'm not sure if I've setup everything correctly and if I have I'm not sure what to pass to the constructor in the `Mappers` class to make it all work?

Console:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapping));

        Learner learner = new Learner();            
    }
}

class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<LearnerDTO, LearnerModel>();
    } 
}
```

Learner Class (in my DataLibrary):

```
public class Learner
{
    public string GetLearner()
    {
        Mappers mappers = new Mappers(); //This Mappers instance is underlined red

        LearnerDTO learnerDTO = JsonFactory.LoadJson();
        LearnerModel learnerModel = mappers.LearnerDTOtoLearnerModel(learnerDTO);
        
    }

}
```

Mappers Class:

```
public class Mappers
{
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public Mappers(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public LearnerModel LearnerDTOtoLearnerModel(LearnerDTO learnerDto)
    {
        LearnerModel model = _mapper.Map<LearnerModel>(learnerDto);

        return model;
    }
}
```

Firstly, I would like some comment on whether I've configured AutoMapper correctly and in the right place? And secondly, if it all looks fine, what do I need to pass into the `Mappers` constructor from the `Learner` class when creating an instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using dependency injection, then the classes should be refactored to allow for that using service abstractions and explicitly dependency principle via constructor injection.

*Learner* class and abstraction

```
public interface ILearner {
    string GetLearner();
}

public class Learner : ILearner {
    private readonly IMappers mappers;

    public Learner(IMappers mappers) {
        this.mappers = mappers;
    }

    public string GetLearner() {    
        LearnerDTO learnerDTO = JsonFactory.LoadJson();
        LearnerModel learnerModel = mappers.LearnerDTOtoLearnerModel(learnerDTO);            
    }    
}
```

*Mappers* class and abstraction

```
public interface IMappers {
    LearnerModel LearnerDTOtoLearnerModel(LearnerDTO learnerDto);
}

public class Mappers : IMappers {
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public Mappers(IMapper mapper) {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public LearnerModel LearnerDTOtoLearnerModel(LearnerDTO learnerDto) {
        LearnerModel model = _mapper.Map<LearnerModel>(learnerDto);    
        return model;
    }
}
```

Everything should then be registered with the dependency container, which will be used to resolve the services and perform the desired function.

*Console*

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapping));
        
        //use the lifetime that suits your needs
        //but for this example I am using transient
        services.AddTransient<ILearner, Learner>(); 
        services.AddTransient<IMappers, Mappers>();
        
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        ILearner learner = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILearner>();

        //...            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm getting further now, but now I'm hitting an exception on the "LearnerModel model = _mapper.Map<LearnerModel>(learnerDto); " line. Exception: AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Comment: Check `AutoMapping` and make sure you have created the mapping correctly in the profile, and that the profile was added when setting up the service collection.

Comment: Yeah, it dawned on me that I have lists with other models / DTOs in my objects so I have created mappings for those as well. All good! Thanks for your help.